# Polynomial congruences: $x^2 + 5x - 9 \equiv 0\mod5^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find all the solutions of $$x^2 + 5x - 9 \equiv 0\mod5^2$$

I know that first I must find the solutions of $f(x)\equiv0\mod 5$ and then "get up" those solutions modulo $5^2$. So
$$f(x)\equiv x^2+1 \equiv0\mod 5\quad \Rightarrow\quad x\equiv 2, x\equiv -2\mod 5$$

But from here on I don't know how to handle the solutions modulo $5$ to get the solutions modulo $5^2$. Any help with proper justifications would be apreciated.

Comment: Ok, so you know that $x\equiv \pm 2 \pmod 5$, so write $x=\pm 2 +5t$ and solve for $t$.  Alternatively, just remark that there aren't very many residues $\pmod {25}$ which are $\pm 2 \pmod 5$ so you could just try each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2+5x-9\equiv2(x^2+5x-9)\equiv0\mod25$$ Now by calculation $x=7$ satisfies the condition. So $x-7  $divides $ 2(x^2+5x-9)$
We have $$2(x^2+5x-9)\equiv(x-7)(2x+24)\equiv0\mod25$$ $$x\equiv7\mod25$$ and $$x\equiv13\mod25$$